# Elements of HTML and CSS not showing up on github

Tags: css, github, github-pages

(I have extensively searched for a solution but nothing that has happened to someone seems to be the problem)

I am a beginner working on a very simple project. I uploaded it to github but github pages won't show the CSS. It works just fine when I run it locally.

It's supposed to look like this:
[snapshot of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeux8.png)

This is the repo: https://github.com/padnama/odin-recipes/

This is the pages link: https://padnama.github.io/odin-recipes/

Answer (score -1):

Your wrongly refered your CSS in HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>receitas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="recipes/images/main.png" alt="the best cook">
        <div class="writings">
            <h1 id="title">receitas</h1>
            <ul id="recipes">
                <li><a href="https://maximilienhe.github.io/odin-recipe/recipes/macarrao.html/risotto.html">risotto</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://maximilienhe.github.io/odin-recipe/recipes/strogonoff_cogumelos.html">strogonoff de cogumelos</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://maximilienhe.github.io/odin-recipe/recipes/macarrao.html">macarrão com amendoim apimentado</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That should work better

Comment: On your local work, the path access of elements of your folder isn't the same as github. Use ./ or shorter path access, as you did with the <img src="recipes/images/main.png">

Comment: Yeah it was like that before and it wasn't working, someone told me to use the full path and it didn't work as well :/ I did change it to what you told me to but it's not working either way

Comment: I did other researched, and I find out that you have to set the path like this :
"https://github.com/padnama/odin-recipes/blob/main/style.css"
So use the origin path "https://github.com/padnama/odin-recipes/blob/main/" and complete it with the other files you want to refer to. I update my answer

Comment: I did a pull request, so you just have to accept it on your repositery @AmandaPereira ! Check the answer as the right one if that works :D

Comment: but will it work locally if I change to that path?

Comment: I think it could, as Github is a form of cloud storage ? Try it to make sure !

Comment: I think I accepted your pull request but I'm not sure if I did... It's still not working.

Comment: Github pages can take some time to make an update, I'll try on my own repo to make sure I'm not saying you dumb things !

Comment: Okay, so if I just do this : ./style.css to reference css, it works on my repo

Answer (score -1):

Add the link of CSS file to your HTML page, see the attached picture below:

[image]